# How to run javascript in firefox console after page load automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, console

Is it possible to run java script in Firefox console after page load automatically.

Or can I set js script for any website url.

Comment: You mean as an end user or as a web site? Do you want to run extra stuff in your own browser (like Greasemonkey) or for other people when they visit your web site?

Comment: I want to run as a website.

Comment: So how is this different than putting a `<script>` tag in your page HTML? What exactly do you mean by "run in Firefox console" (and what should it do for Safari, IE, Chrome folks)?

Comment: I am creating a service which is Firefox specific. And trying to find best place to put my js. Probably I should write in <script> tag but also searching for console based things.